Using curl/flask I can't make user to both download a file and get messages on the command prompt
I have built a python api that accepts two inputs and produce a json file as an output.
The user should be able to get the file via a curl command (Flask has been used in the api). It works fine. However, if I use the parameter -O so that user downloads the output file, then messages from "return jsonify" are not printed on the user command prompt. If I don't use -O, then the messages from "return jsonify" get printed on the command prompt but the file is not downloaded, instead it is printed on the command prompt.
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/extract -F ..... -F ..... -O
(this works well and file is downloaded. However, if for example the user forgets to add the first parameter, the corresponding error message -written in the python api as a "return jsonfiy" message- is not printed on the user command prompt)
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/extract -F ..... -F .....
(This prints error messages from "return jsonify on the user command prompt. However, when there's no errors, the output json file is printed on the user command prompt instead of being downloaded)
Is there anyway to have both things at the same time?

User being able to dowload the output file
If user makes an error (like forgetting one of the input parameters), the corresponding error message ("return jsonify ....") is printed on the user command prompt.


If you want to make curl write content to a file if the error is 2xx-value, and to stderr in the case of an exit status reflecting an error, I'm not sure that has anything at all to do with flask or Python -- it's the same changes to curl usage no matter how the server is implemented, so you could ask a narrower question (or get better search results by doing the initial search using terms more narrowly focused on the immediate problem at hand).
